# For each loop using 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

This is the snippet of Java code:

```
int[][] uu = new int[1][1];
uu[0][0] = 5;
for(int[] u: uu){
    System.out.println(u[0]);
}
```

It prints 5. But why does the declaration part of for loop is declared `as int[] u`, but not `as int[][] u`?

At the uu you reference 2D array...
That is not a homework. I am preparing for Java certification.
Cheers

Comment: Just a silly suggestion: - Its not `2-D array` in Java. Its an `array of array`.

Comment: It is implemented in the way of array in array, but it is called 2D array in books.

Comment: @uml.. May be, but still an `array of array` is a better term to name it. You will know it in future. :)

Comment: @uml I know a lot of books call it a 2D array, and if I needed a 2D array in a Java program I would map it to this structure, but it really is an array of arrays, and it is much better to think of it that way. For example, the answer to your question becomes obvious if you think of the for loop as iterating over an array, each of whose elements is an int[].

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Since your `uu` is an `array of array`. So, when you iterate over it, you will first get an `array`, and then you can iterate over that array to get individual elements.

So, your outer loop has `int[]` as type, and hence that declaration. If you iterate through your `u` in one more inner loop, you will get the type `int`: -

```
for (int[] u: uu) {
    for (int elem: u) {
        // Your individual element
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is because `uu` is an array of `int[]` arrays. So every item in it is `int[]`. In a `for` loop you declare the type of an item in an array you iterate over.

Answer (score 2):

The loop is iterating on the elements of `uu`, which are objects of type `int[]`. (Or in other words - `u` is an element in `uu`, thus it is an `int[]`).

The declaration is always of the type of the objects retrieved by the iteration - in this case - it is `int[]` -

Same as iterating over an `int[]` is:

```
 for (int x : myArray) { ...}
```

because each element of `x` is of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

*"why does the declaration part of for loop is declared as int[] u, but not as int[][] u?"*

The array is two-dimensional, so you are dealing with a double-layered iteration. You have an array "inside" another, in the same principle as `List<List<Integer>>` would work.

To iterate through all the elements, you should consider a rows-elements structure. It's necessary that you get each row from the container, and then each element from each row.

`for(int[] u: uu)` is simply a for-each iteration rows, with the same principle of `for(int row = 0; row < container.length; row++)`, and `u` or respectively `container[row]` are not elements themselves, but rows (arrays) of elements. Meaning you require a second iteration layer to get the elements:

```
int[][] container = new int[10][10];
//... - Fill elements.
for(int row = 0; row < container.length; row++){
  for(int element = 0; element < container[row].length; element++){
    System.out.printf("Row: %d Element: %d Value: %d\n", row, element, container[row][element]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an example of finding the sum in 2d array and print it

```
public class Array2DForEach {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int[][] myFirst2DArray = {
                                    { 3, 5, 1, 9 },
                                    { 10, 15, 3, 0  },
                                    { 1, 11, 31, 90 },
                                    { 2, 51, 1, 9 }
                                };

        for (int[] row:myFirst2DArray) {

            for (int columnElement : row) {
                sum+=columnElement;
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer does not answers the asked question