# Can I use an enhanced for loop to print two dimensional arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I am learning about these things and I am used to using regular iterator for loops. Anyway, I was wondering if I could print this simple array:

```
    public class enchancedtwodimdemo
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String[][] chords = {{"A", "C", "D", "E"},{"Am","Dm"}};
    }    

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Your code soesn't compile. A 2D array is in fact an array of arrays. And each you can use a foreach loop on arrays. So you have the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383692/for-each-loop-using-2d-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You can use one enhanced-for to get at the "inner" `String[]`s, and then another to print each `String` within that.

(I presume you meant to write `String[][] = {{...}}`.)

There's no general way of getting at the leaf elements of a nested structure. But if all you want to do is to print it, you could take a look at [`Arrays.deepToString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29), which [handles that nested access for you](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,java.lang.StringBuilder,java.util.Set%29).

Comment: "There's no general way of printing nested arrays built into the language" <-- [the language, no, the API, yes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[]))

Comment: @fge Thanks! I knew there was something... was looking. Will edit. :)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can do like this:

```
for(String[] str:chords) {
   for(String value:str) {
      //Do anything with 'value' here
   }
}
```

I haven't compiled, but this should work.

Comment: You better **do** try to compile.

Comment: **No**, what is `array`?

Comment: I was in process of editing, meanwhile people downvoted!!! Sad.. Didn't had compiler in front, typo happens. But there is edit option right?? I hope SO did had a option like "Person X is editing the post.. " just like in chats :)

Comment: 5 comments written here just to convey a small message `change value to str`. :-/ @PradeepSimha You should change the comment also :)  +1

Comment: @PM 77-1.. as I mentioned in my comments, I WAS in the process of EDITING.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `String[]` is a one-dimensional array. A two-dimensional array would be:

```
String[][] chords = { { "A", "C", "D", "E" }, { "Am", "Dm" } };
```

and you can use enhanced-for loops to loop first, through 1-D arrays (`String[]`) and then to loop through each `String`:

```
for (String[] array : chords) {
    for (String string : array) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Note** that when you use an enhanced-for loop, **you have to specifiy the type** of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Muti-Dimentional Array is an array of array. Try to add this to your code:

```
    for (String rows[]: chords) {
        for(String cols: rows) {
            System.out.println(cols+"\t");
        }
            System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, we can definetly do so using enhanced for loop.**

```
int arr[][] = { { 1, 2, 3 },
                     { 4, 5, 6 },
                     { 7, 8, 9 } };

for(int[] i:arr){

    for(int a:i){

        System.out.print(a);


    }

    System.out.println();

}
```